# php curl hanging and infinite loop

Tags: php

i have been working on a scraper tool that rips google search results and then crawls the results websites looking to match specific items.

I'm having an issue with cURL though. I have come accross a site that is causing curl to go into an infinite loop.

website in question.
http://www.darellyelectrical.com/

when i open up my packet sniffer and look through tcp http packets ive found the same request is being sent over and over again.

i can not pinpoint the reason why, I have no trouble with any other websites.

I have tried setting the following curl options

curl_setopt($this->sessions[$key], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

curl_setopt($this->sessions[$key], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);

curl_setopt($this->sessions[$key], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);

be great if someone could test that url with curl and let me know if the issue persists.

thanks

EDIT****

```
    function sck_send() 
{

    $host = "www.darellyelectrical.com";
    $path = "";

    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {

        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";

    } else {



        $out = "GET /".$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        $data = "";

        fwrite($fp, $out);

        while (!feof($fp)) 
        {
            $data .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }

        fclose($fp);

        echo $data;
    }

}
```

sck_send();

```
this will produce the loop same as curl.
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: I've just made an attempt to open the same domain with a socket connection the loop still continues. I have added the code to the original post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That server needs the User-Agent header to be included or it does not respond. PHP's curl doesn't set this by default and it wouldn't be included in a socket request unless you specify it. The code below works for me:

```
<?php

function sck_send()  {
    $host = "www.darellyelectrical.com";
    $path = "";
    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        $out = "GET /".$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 \r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        $data = "";
        fwrite($fp, $out);

        while (!feof($fp))  {
            $data .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }

        fclose($fp);
        echo $data;
    }
}
sck_send();
```